# Alphabet constant in Java?

Tags: java, constants

I have a situation where I need to find a letter's index in the alphabet. In Python I could use `string.ascii_lowercase` or `string.ascii_uppercase`. Is there something similar in Java?

Obviously I could do:

```
private static char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
```

But after so much Python, it makes me wonder if this is built in somewhere.

Comment: Which alphabet?  English speaking persons frequently get a surprise when they find out about non-English alphabets.

Comment: I'm not actually use it as an alphabet, I just have some "numbers" in base 26 (which happens to be the Latin alphabet).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the index like this:

```
char lowercaseLetter = ...
int index = lowercaseLetter - 'a';
```

Comment: Nice idea. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

Although I would prefer ColinD's approach whenever it fits I just want to mention that Java actually has some sort of API for this. It allows you to parse numbers with a radix of up to 36 which use the 10 digits from `'0'-'9'` and the letters `'a'-'z'` for the rest of the range (in either case).

```
char letter = ...
int index = Character.digit( letter, 36 ) - 10;
```

and back

```
int index = ...
char ch = Character.forDigit( index + 10, 36 );
```

In case you actually want to use this to create or parse radix 36 numbers, you can use the `Integer.parseInt` and `Integer.toString` static method implementations that take a radix parameter.